# Routing 4 Networks

Tags: linux, debian, routing, route

I've been trying for almost a week to make it work but without success. I'm starting to feel hopeless.

I have 4 Ethernet adapters :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:ad:54:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.100.36.2/29 brd 10.100.36.7 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::3285:a9ff:fead:541e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:f3:c1:04:64:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 69.70.164.242/30 brd 69.70.164.243 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe04:6440/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:f3:c1:04:a0:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.45.13.1/24 brd 10.45.13.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe04:a02f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:10:7b:c9:58:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.45.15.1/24 brd 10.45.15.255 scope global eth3
    inet6 fe80::2a10:7bff:fec9:5876/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is the default route my linux server (Debian) give me at startup :

```
69.70.164.240/30 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 69.70.164.242
10.100.36.0/29 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.36.2
10.45.15.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.45.15.1
10.45.13.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.45.13.1
default via 10.45.15.254 dev eth3
default via 10.45.13.254 dev eth2
default via 69.70.164.241 dev eth1
default via 10.100.36.1 dev eth0
```

Here's what I want to do. eth0 is my VDSL line and eth1 is my cable line. I want to:

- Forward all traffic from `10.45.13.0` (eth2) to the gateway `10.100.36.1` (eth0)
- Forward all traffic from `10.45.15.0` (eth3) to the gateway `69.70.164.241` (eth1)

If I make this work, I would be happy enough but I would also like to make `10.45.13.0` invisible from `10.45.15.0` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one default route ... per routing table. So at first you need to remove all default routes but one. The one route you would like your debian server to use.

For your other stuff, what you want is called "source routing", which means you perform different routing, based on the origin (source) of the currently handled packet.

[This](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html) is an example for actually precicely what you want to do with source routing. Your question is formulated a little bit wobbly, so I will assume you want your debian server to use your VDSL line as well.

This means you want to remove all default routes from your routing table, but the one via eth0. Your main/locat RT should look like this then:

```
69.70.164.240/30 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 69.70.164.242
10.100.36.0/29 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.36.2
10.45.15.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.45.15.1
10.45.13.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.45.13.1
default via 10.100.36.1 dev eth0
```

Then you create another routing table following the linked example. You probably rather want to call that table `UseCable` instead of `John`. So you could go

```
echo 200 UseCable >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

And then you tell your kernel to use that table when packet originate from `10.45.13.0` like this:

```
ip rule add from 10.45.15.0 table UseCable
```

Then you need to populate UseCable. The following is a start:

```
ip route add 10.45.15.0/24 dev eth3 table UseCable
ip route add 69.70.164.240/30 dev eth1 table UseCable
ip route add default via 69.70.164.241 table UseCable #that's the default route via cable
```

Well, then you are done in terms of routing. I think you want NAT as well. So you need something along the lines of

```
#for everything from eth3 leaving through eth1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE 

#for everything from eth2 leaving through eth0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Done. It is not the most clean of ways but communication between 10.45.13.0/24 and 10.45.15.0/24 is not possible because when originating from 10.45.15.0/24 the routing table does not contain an entry for 10.45.13.0/24.

I leave the refinement as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It's a bit more clear to me now. Yes, VDSL line is the default used by the server, you are right. I will try this today. When you say "remove all default route", I do `ip route del X` where X is all my route except eth0. After, I add my rule to the table and I do the NAT using iptables ?

Comment: you need to specify the whole "default via xxx" for route del.

Comment: Ok. I only have `10.100.36.0/29 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.36.2` and `default via 10.100.36.1 dev eth0` in my main table. I also have the `UseCable` you made me do. I added the command to iptables (I removed -I because you cannot use -I with POSTROUTING). However, it doesn't work yet. I am trying other stuff from what you gave me now.

Comment: When I try to ping from my client machine (either 45.13 or 15.15), my client is unable to ping.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the RTs you need. You were supposed to only delete all DEFAULT routes but one. Not all the routes.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I imagine you wanted to say `ip route add 69.70.164.240/30 dev eth1 table UseCable` instead ? I will try that later today.

Comment: I made it work with your help. Thanks you so much. However, `ip rule add from 10.45.15.0 table UseCable` didn't work. I had to do `ip rule add from 10.45.15.1 table UseCable`, `ip rule add from 10.45.15.2 table UseCable`, etc. I don't know why. I even tryed ti add the mask bit but it didn't work either.

Comment: `ip rule add from 10.45.15.0/24 table UseCable` probably does the trick

Comment: Like I said, I did try it but for some reason it didn't work...

Comment: even with the /24 ?

Comment: Yes. I'll attempt again tomorrow, I have nothing to loose !

Comment: Thanks you for your help, it's working like a charm since one week. the bit masking didn't work.